# Making ridges method on a cube mesh

Tags: modeling

I have a wooden box in my example which looks like its made out of different wooden pieces. I'm trying to find a good method how to make it look its from separate pieces. So In my example I made loop cuts, and extruded the faces along the normals. would this be the right approach, or would it be incorrect to just make up a box from different meshes to get the ridge look where the red arrows are pointing?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: yes why not making separate meshes, it will simplify your work

Comment: Hey Moonboots, I wanted to make sure I'm not breaking any 3D modelling rules, and I take a correct approach. Thank you for your advice.